# error on update

Tags: 8, updating

I just updated from Drupal 8.1.x to 8.2.5 manually, I delete core and vendor folders first, and all the roots files from my instalaion, but When I try to acces the update.php I get this error,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Database\Connection' not found in /home/<username>/public_html/blog/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php on line 22
```

The site is in a PHP 7.0 server, I checked the settings.php file and it is correct I am trying Drupal for the first time, and I don´t know what to do. Installation was working fine. Somebody Knows how to fix this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you clear the cache in the UI? (Configuration > Development > Performance > Clear cache button) And then try again. Maybe there is still some cached data somewhere.

Comment: I can't access to Administrator panel, I can't access anything, it just display that error in a white screen. I tried deleting chrome cache and nothing happened. Thanks for the answer.